# Concatenate string and field value on xml odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

To the point of the question

I have code

```
<t t-set="get_data_remain" t-value="o.execute_sql('
                        SELECT
                            SUM(a.qty) totalQty,
                            a.product_id,
                            b.name
                        FROM marketing_forecast_remain a
                        INNER JOIN product_template b
                        ON a.product_id = b.id
                        WHERE a.marketing_forecast_id = 65
                        GROUP BY a.product_id, b.name
                        ORDER BY b.name
                        ;
                    ')"/>
```

I call function in .py to execute my sql from view (xml)

The problem is I want change value of parameter of my query (WHERE conditions)

```
WHERE a.marketing_forecast_id = 65
```

to be

```
WHERE a.marketing_forecast_id = value of id field (field value from .py)
```

someone please help me?

thanks in advance.

*Correct me if im wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**SOLVED**]

I move my query to **.py** so i dont need try hard to make conditions in xml

```
    def execute_sql(self):
    query = "SELECT SUM(a.qty) totalQty, a.product_id, b.name " \
            "FROM marketing_forecast_remain a " \
            "INNER JOIN product_template b " \
            "ON a.product_id = b.id " \
            "WHERE a.marketing_forecast_id = %s " \
            "GROUP BY a.product_id, b.name " \
            "ORDER BY b.name;"

    param = [self.id]

    self._cr.execute(query,param)
    _hasil = self._cr.dictfetchall()
    return _hasil
```

**%s** this is the parameter i've set then i give value by this code

```
        param = [self.id]

    self._cr.execute(query,param)
```

So in my view (xml) i just need to call the method like this

```
                        <t t-set="get_data_remain" t-value="o.execute_sql()"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
<t t-set="get_data_remain" t-value="o.execute_sql('
                    SELECT
                        SUM(a.qty) totalQty,
                        a.product_id,
                        b.name
                    FROM marketing_forecast_remain a
                    INNER JOIN product_template b
                    ON a.product_id = b.id
                    WHERE a.marketing_forecast_id = %s
                    GROUP BY a.product_id, b.name
                    ORDER BY b.name
                    ;
                ') %value"/>


<t t-set="get_data_remain" t-value="o.execute_sql('
                    SELECT
                        SUM(a.qty) totalQty,
                        a.product_id,
                        b.name
                    FROM marketing_forecast_remain a
                    INNER JOIN product_template b
                    ON a.product_id = b.id
                    WHERE a.marketing_forecast_id = value
                    GROUP BY a.product_id, b.name
                    ORDER BY b.name
                    ;
                ')"/>
replace value with your field
```

Comment: I got this error ProgrammingError: 'sintaks error' pada atau didekat « % »
LINE 1: ...                  WHERE a.marketing_forecast_id = %s        ...

Comment: Then try to give value directly, see my updated anwser

Comment: value which i want to set as operand in conditions is value from odoo's field, not field between two tables which i've selected, I've tried this                     WHERE a.marketing_forecast_id = o.id (o.id is my field i mean)